# How Can I see the Sql query of the excel file I uploaded Oracle DB

Tags: excel, oracle

I am learning pl/sql. I want to ask a question for importing excel files.
I create a table after that import data from excel nearly 100 rows. 
I wonder how can i see this query basic like;

```
insert into table_name (column1,colum2,...,columnn )
values (value1, value2, ... , value n); and other 100 rows..
```

Sincerely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether there is a feature within Oracle engine itself, but I can think of two ways to get those queries:

**1. Use Oracle SQL Developer (Or another GUI with the same features) :**

Oracle SQL Developer (Download link [here](https://www.oracle.com/tools/downloads/sqldev-v192-downloads.html)) is a free tool developed by Oracle to interact with the database. Add the connection for your database and connect to it, then follow [these](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/04/how-to-import-from-excel-to-oracle-with-sql-developer/) guidelines carefully to generate your insert script.

**2. Use v$sql (Experimental) :**

Right now I have no access to an Oracle database to check this, but theoretically, if the database is a development/training one, there should not be a lot of activities and queries inside, so you can query the `v$sql` table to find the last 100 (or whatsoever) queries:

```
SELECT SQL_FULLTEXT FROM V$SQL WHERE ROWNUM < 1000 ORDER BY FIRST_LOAD_TIME desc;
```

Check for the ones starting with `INSERT INTO {THE_TABLE_WHICH_HAS_IMPORTED_DATA}` to find your insert lines.
As I mentioned, this method is quite experimental and might confuse you, so I strongly suggest using Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I am using Pl/sql developer. this response helpful me. 
I am asking another question,
If i insert 100 rows on the table, i select them and how can i see this rows query?

Comment: Okey, I found. 
Data Column --> Export Data --> Insert column. They gave me, all rows.